# Streamlit deploy error with cv2 and with streamlit lib

Tags: streamlit

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)

File "/app/pencilsketch_webapp/webapp.py", line 4, in 
import cv2

Answer (score 0):

Although I need to see your scripts and Procfile/Dockerfile for solving this properly but analyzing your error code I can see there is an issue with opencv.

#### A possible fix if it is purely related to deployment:

In the `requirements.txt` file put `opencv-python` instead of `cv2`